# How to prioritise an image extension when including a picture?

Tags: graphics

I have some pictures saved at the same time in different image extensions, for example, pic1.png, pic1.pdf, pic1.jpg, pic2.pdf, pic2.png, pic3.jpg.

I would like to include preferably .pdf, if not, .png, and as last option .jpg, if no other format is available, when I include the picture in my LaTeX document using `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that with this extensions, .pdf, .png, .jpg, (but not with .eps) I can determine the priority that the command `includegraphics` will use, if I declare the extensions in the desired order using `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions`. For example, in my case I would write  `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}`  to fix the priorities in this order .pdf, .png, and .jpg

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{pic1}
\includegraphics{pic2}
\includegraphics{pic3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is documented in `texdoc grfguide`  the same mechanism works for whatever file formats are supported by the driver you are using  (although the details for eps with pdftex or luatex are a bit different as that requires a shell process to convert to pdf in the background)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good to know. I really thought, it was something casual. I did not read the `texdoc grfguide`. Maybe I should read more guides instead of experimenting with latex. The question is: which of both methods is less time consuming? ;)